# How to get the array of all keys from the dictionary in the existing order?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sequentialy access a dictionary??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854542/how-to-sequentialy-access-a-dictionary)

I have a dictionary , I want to reitrive all keys in an array with the same order which exist inside the dictionary . The documentation on "allKeys" method of NSDictionary says the order of returned objects in array is not defined . What can be done to get the keys in the same order as that of the dictionary .

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: yes , sorry but the way I sentenced the question , I did not find that page in the result . Thank you anyways , I am checking the link :)

Answer (score 0):

So the question you were pointed to summarises the issue nicely, but the solutions offered could be a little bit too complex for your needs (if you didn't want / have the time to write a sub-class or your own data structure).

The quick and dirty alternative is simple to have an array that contains all the keys you want to access in the order you want to access them in. You can then simply match this array back to your dictionary to pull out values in the correct order.

Comment: The solution I posted on the linked question implements this "quick-and-dirty" solution; it just wraps up the array in the same class  with the dict so that no other object has to worry about it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply . Well thanx for the solution . But i had applied even dirtier logic in my application ;) . I had very less time and had to go for that I am literally comparing the keys from my dictionary with some hardcoded strings . . :( . I will have a look at this issue when I get some time and will try to create a dictianory subclass which can serve the purpose. Thanks all for answering !!